# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," in react jsx when adding <img>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I get this error in my component:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../../Images/Logo.svg';

class Simulate extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            this.state.wentWrong?
             (<div className="went-wrong-box">
                <div className="went-wrong-title">
                    <div className="went-wrong-title__img">
                        <img src={logo} alt="Logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
            :
            (<div>
                Other Content
            </div>)
        )
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem in the image tag, although the logo used in src is already imported, this happens also if I replaced the logo in src with a string, but if I removed the image, it works:

```
return(
    this.state.wentWrong?
     (<div className="went-wrong-box">
        <div className="went-wrong-title">
            <div className="went-wrong-title__img">

            </div>
        </div>
    <div>)
    :
    (<div>
        Other Content
    </div>)
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You've got a `<div>` where you should have `</div>`

Comment: @Pointy this was a typo, edited

Comment: I think JSX doesn’t support unclosed tags. Make `<img/>` self closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close your `<img>` and last `<div>` tags.

```
(<div className="went-wrong-box">
      <div className="went-wrong-title">
          <div className="went-wrong-title__img">
              <img src={logo} alt="Logo" /> // <- close this
          </div>
      </div>
</div>) // <- close this
```

Comment: yes, the problem was I missed to close the img